# Grant a user permission to only view a MySQL view and nothing else

Tags: mysql, view, permissions, database-permissions, sql-grant

This question was originally using MySQL 5.1.44, but is applicable to MySQL 8.0+ too.

Let's say I have a table with records inserted by different users of my application. How can I give a specific user access to only see his/her records in that table? I've thought about creating a `VIEW` with his/her records, but I  don't know how to create a MySQL user that can only see that `VIEW`.

So, is it possible to create a MySQL user that only has access to a single `VIEW`? Can this user also be made so they read-only access to that `VIEW`?

Thanks!

PS: What I call *users* in my example are really subsidiary offices that want to access their records with their own applications.

Comment: Views are read-only if they don't have triggers.

Comment: For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a view nonupdatable.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`GRANT SELECT ON database1.view1 TO 'someuser'@'somehost';`

Comment: Please note that the user that issues the create view command (called the view definer) also has influence on this. if definer != user that uses the view, than this can be quite confusing. For example if the definer has only select permissions on the underlying table, and another user has update permissions on the view, then trying to update the view will cause a permission denied error.

Answer (score 17):

Besides

```
GRANT SELECT ON <database_name>.<view_name>
TO <user>@<host>
```

it's better to also do

```
GRANT SHOW VIEW
ON <database_name>.<view_name> TO <user>@<host>
```

so that a lot of SQL UI tool can get the view definition and work appropriately for the view.

Comment: There's no `IDENTIFIED BY` in `GRANT` command. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Answer (score 6):

```
GRANT SELECT ON <database name>.<view name>
TO <user>@<host> IDENTIFIED BY '<password>'
```

Source: [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0006100000)

Answer (score 6):

I believe the original question is actually asking how to limit the rows to those owned by a given user.  (The idea of creating one view per user, and then granting just that, seems like a workaround.)

You can do this by inserting the user() reference into the data table, and then filtering on that.

Using MySQL 5.6.  Create a view that limits SELECT to just records owned by the current user:

```
-- check the current user
select user();

create table t1 (myId int, mydata varchar(200), myName varchar(200));

insert t1 select 1, 'my data yes', user();
insert t1 select 2, 'my data yes2', user();
insert t1 select 3, 'my data no', 'joe';

select * from t1;

create or replace view v1 AS
select * from t1 where myName = user();

select * from v1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the view read only which I suspect you do.  Then you should create the view with the ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE clause.

This will make the view read only virtue of it having to create a temp table.

Another way to achieve read only and this is depends on your data is to stick an aggregate function.  For example if you have a view which is based on a table and shows all columns then you can stick a distinct onto the select.